# Why are many unable to defecate and urinate simultaneously?

Tags: human-biology, physiology

Many people (including myself) do not defecate and urinate simultaneously, but rather in succession.  Only after one is completed, the other commences.  I have noticed this in myself, but the internet suggests this is neither unique nor universal: for example, see [quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-impossible-or-difficult-for-a-man-to-urinate-and-defecate-at-the-same-time), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/m2yey/do_women_defecate_and_urinate_simultaneously_pee/), [grasscity](https://forum.grasscity.com/threads/pooping-and-peeing-at-the-same-time-possible-or-impossible.673870/).  I don't seem to find any references explaining why people would be unable to do both at the same time.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because we don't deal in personal health questions here. I usually just vote to close in those cases, and usually leave an explanatory comment, but people are free to downvote as well.

Comment: @BryanKrause I see.  I never intended to ask a personal health question but I can imagine why it may be perceived as such with the personal introduction.  I have reformulated it to be more generic.

Comment: After the edit, this does not appear like a personal medical question. I recommend reopening.

Comment: Something related to increasing pelvic/abdominal pressure during urination mandates external sphincter to contract simuntaneously.